# Aggregation Framework on Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to aggregate datas by Date in Mongo, but I can't quite achieve what I want. 
Right now, I'm using this:

```
db.aggregData.aggregate( { $group: {_id: "$Date".toString(),  
                                   tweets: { $sum: "$CrawledTweets"} } }, 
                         { $match:{ _id: {$gte: ISODate("2013-03-19T12:31:00.247Z") }}}, 
                         { $sort: {Date:-1} } 
                       )
```

It results with this:

```
"result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-19T12:50:00.641Z"),
                        "tweets" : 114
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-19T12:45:00.631Z"),
                        "tweets" : 114
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-19T12:55:00.640Z"),
                        "tweets" : 123
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-19T12:40:00.628Z"),
                        "tweets" : 91
                    },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-19T12:31:00.253Z"),
                        "tweets" : 43
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-19T13:20:00.652Z"),
                        "tweets" : 125
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ISODate("2013-03-19T12:31:00.252Z"),
                        "tweets" : 30
                }
 ],
        "ok" : 1
```

It seems to do the job, but with further inspection, we see that there is repetition:
ISODate("2013-03-19T12:31:00.253Z") and ISODate("2013-03-19T12:31:00.252Z").
The only thing that changes is the last bit before the Z.

So here is my question. What is this part ? And how can I do to ignore it in the aggregation ?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I wanna aggregate by date, so whole year/month/day + hour and minute. I don't care of the rest.

EDIT: My db in on mongolab, so I'm on 2.2

Well, I did it another way: I save all my date with seconds/milliseconds at 0. So I can keep a simple aggregate, with not a little more code server side, thanks to moment.js

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to aggregate by "whole" date, in other words to drop the time from ISODate(), right?  There are several ways to do it, I describe them in detail on my blog in the post called

[Stupid Date Tricks with Aggregation Framework](http://www.kamsky.org/1/post/2013/03/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework.html).

You can see the full step-by-step breakdown there, but to summarize you have two choices:

- if you don't care about the aggregated-on value to be an `ISODate()` then you can use the `{$year}`, `{$month}` and `{$dayOfMonth}` operators in `{$project}` phase to pull out just Y-M-D to then {$group} on.
- if you do care about the grouped-on value staying an `ISODate` you can `{$subtract}` the time part in `{$project}` phase and be left with `ISODate()` type - the caveat is that this method requires MongoDB 2.4 [(just released)](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/45754637343/mongodb-2-4-released) which adds support for date arithmetic and for `$millisecond` operator (see exact code in the blog post).

Here is probably what you want:

```
db.aggregData.aggregate([
  { 
    $project:{ 
        CrawledTweets: 1,
        newDate: { 
            year:{$year:"$Date"}, 
            month: {$month:"$Date"}, 
            day: {$dayOfMonth:"$Date"}, 
            hour: {$hour: "$Date"}, 
            min: {$minute: "$Date"}
        }   
    }   
  },
  { 
    $group: {
        _id: "$newDate",
        tweets: { $sum: "$CrawledTweets"}
    }   
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks I'll read. I should have said, but I wanna aggregate by date, so whole year/month/day + hour and minute. I don't care of the rest.

Comment: hour and minute means you're aggregating by minute - but it's simple to extend either of the paths to what you want.  Like I said, if you're on 2.2 then use the first way, {$project:{year:{$year:"$Date"}, month:{$month:"$Date"}, etc} otherwise in your already grabbed 2.4 I recommend the way in the blog post using {$subtract} to get rid of $millisecond part.

Comment: I really don't understand how this works. I can't reproduce the exemple and make it works.

Comment: what did you try and what was the error (or incorrect result)?  I'd be happy to help get it to correct form if I know exactly what you are looking for.  First, which version of MongoDB are you using and which of the two methods I described are you trying to use first or second?

Answer (score 1):

Without being a Mongo expert and without knowing your db fields I'd come up with something like this. Perhaps you can build upon this:

```
db.aggregData.aggregate(
{ 
    $project:{ 
        CrawledTweets: 1,
        groupedTime: { 
            year:{$year:"$_id"}, 
            month: {$month:"$_id"}, 
            day: {$dayOfMonth:"$_id"}, 
            hour: {$hour: "$_id"}, 
            min: {$minute: "$_id"}
        }   
    }   
},
{ 
    $group: {
        _id: { groupedTime: "$CrawledTweets" },
        tweets: { $sum: "$tweets"}
    }   
}
)
```

Comment: I got an error that $min, does not exist and with $minute, I have "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type OID to Date". Thanks anyway man :)

Comment: Can you put an input record into your question? It's easier to find a solution if we know the fields/types.

Comment: $min does not exist but there is $minute operator.  Also, his date is stored in "Date" field not _id.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the MongoDB date aggregation operators, I have a post on my blog that goes over the Schema setup, using it in Node.js, etc:

http://smyl.es/how-to-use-mongodb-date-aggregation-operators-in-node-js-with-mongoose-dayofmonth-dayofyear-dayofweek-etc/